# Simple C program disassembled with Ghidra

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c, ghidra

I am trying to figure out what is going on with my simple example programs, when I disassemble them with Ghidra. I am not sure whether this is some strange Ghidra behaviour or something that is set by default during compile time which produce a lot of assembly code, but I actively write only few LOC.

Here is my sample C program created with VS Studio 2017:

```
void main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    x = x + y;
}
```

And this is what I get when I try to disassemble it with Ghidra:

[image]

The above screenshot is from the supposed 'entry' point of the program. But why is it so complex? I did a simple program to test how local variables are presented in Assembly and I get such output. Yet it should be few simple Assembly commands instead.

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing out here, so if someone could help me to try and understand this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Program entry point != `main`

You're seeing disassembly of a few of the functions automatically linked to the program by the compiler toolchain that are responsible for setting up the *C Run-Time* (CRT) environment.

From Microsoft's [CRT Initialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-initialization?view=vs-2019):

> By default, the linker includes the CRT library, which provides its own startup code. This startup code initializes the CRT library, calls global initializers, and then calls the user-provided `main` function for console applications.

From [What is the difference between main and mainCRTStartup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934206/what-is-the-difference-between-main-and-maincrtstartup):

> `main()` is the entry point of your C or C++ program. `mainCRTStartup()` is the entrypoint of the C runtime library. It initializes the CRT, calls any static initializers that you wrote in your code, then calls your `main()` function.

An exercise you may find interesting is compiling the following code (assuming VS Studio 2017 allows it) and then disassembling the resulting binary:

`int main(){}`

Here is the Linux version: [Linux x86 Program Start Up](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html)

Comment: Thank you Julian, a bit clearer now. However, where can I find my main function then? I cannot locate it.

Comment: @Rebegin `main` should be called at some point by `mainCRTStartup`. If you're still having a hard time finding it in the disassembly of the program, you can first run the program using a debugger and set a breakpoint at `main`, look at the call stack, and then revisit the disassembly and decompilation produced by Ghidra

Comment: Thanks Julian, nice tips. Will do that. I have one other question, but I will open another thread here, because it requires a bit more information. I am essentially trying to learn difference between Global vs Local variables in Assembly. I know the theory that global are stored in Memory, and Local variables are on Stack, but I want to see it with my C code and my disassembly.

Comment: @Rebegin you are welcome